# Angular HttpClient: Property 'headers' does not exist on type 'Blob'

Tags: angular, blob, httpclient

i am using angular 5 and this is my code to download file from server:

1- Service:

```
export(url) {
return this.http.get(url, {responseType: 'blob'});
```

2-Component code:

```
  public downloadfile(file: any) {

    var resp: any;
    this.documentsService.export('http://localhost:55650/api/files/attachment/' + file.docf_GUID)
        .subscribe(
            (data) =>{  
                resp = data, saveAs(resp), console.log(resp.headers) },
            () => { }
        );
}
```

But when i try to get Response Headers i get this error:

> error TS2339: Property 'headers' does not exist on type 'Blob'.

Comment: change responseType to ResponseContentType.ArrayBuffer

Answer (score 7):

By default the body of the response is returned. you have to explicilty set the method to return reposne by adding the observe parameter to httpOptions.

```
return this.http.get(url, {responseType: 'blob', observe: 'response'});
```