# Not able to get header from http.get angular 2+

Tags: angular, header-files

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBCGK.png)

```
This is my API call In **report.service.ts** 

  downloadReport(id) :Observable<HttpResponse<Blob>>{
    return this.http.get<Blob>(environment.baseUrl + 'files?id='+id, {
      observe: 'response',
      responseType: 'blob' as 'json'
    });
  }

call in **report.componenet.ts** file
 this.reportsService.downloadReport(arg.fileName).subscribe((data) => {
        console.log(data.headers.get('content-disposition'));
        let d = data.body
          let blob = new Blob([d], {type: 'application/pdf'});
          var downloadURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(d);
          var link = document.createElement('a');
          link.href = downloadURL;
          link.download = "report.pdf";
          link.click();
        })
```

the file is downloading properly but not able to get the name of the file
so I can replace here **link.download = "report.pdf";** with dynamic file name

Comment: can you create sample stackblitz ?

Comment: Do you have control over the backend? If so try to send the file name using a custom header. It appears at the moment the headers do not contain the file name.

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With,content-type,Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="123.jpg"
Content-Length: 89996
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Date: Tue, 22 Sep 2020 07:19:13 GMT
Last-Modified: Mon, 21 Sep 2020 05:27:20 GMT
I am getting all the information which i need but not able to access it

Comment: var downloadURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(  d  change to blob ); need to use your blob variable instead d

Comment: HI @V.Tur the d contains the body of the file 
 let d = data.body
so there is a no problem

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but I also got the same issue as you, Below show my solution that I tweaked based on your code & also some explanation. (I assumed you got no problem with your backend).

I changed the `responseType` value from `'blob' as 'json'` to `'blob'`. In my case, I'm able to fetch the filename without the need to convert the blob to JSON. See below:-

**report.service.ts**

```
downloadReport(id) :Observable<HttpResponse<Blob>>{
    return this.http.get<Blob>(environment.baseUrl + 'files?id='+id, {
      observe: 'response',
      responseType: 'blob'
    });
}
```

For the calling method:-

1. I initialized a new Blob, where I use this two-parameter; First, I Used Blobpart like this one `data.body as Blobpart`. Second,  I fetched `Content-Disposition` from response headers and assigned it as a string value to the `type` property.
2. I fetched `Content-Disposition` from the response header assigned to the variable and filter the value before I assigned it to the `link.download` property.

**report.component.ts**

```
 this.reportsService.downloadReport(arg.fileName).subscribe((data) => {

    console.log(data.headers.get('content-disposition'));

    // Initialize new blob from response
    let d = new Blob([data.body as BlobPart], {type: (data.headers.get('Content-Type'))?.toString()});

    // Fetch Content disposition from response headers
    const contentDispositionHeader = data.headers.get('Content-Disposition');

    // Download a file if content disposition header exist
    if (contentDispositionHeader !== null) {
        // Split a string to an array of substring by ';' sepearator, 
        // then remove white space within that array of substring 
        // then split the result to an array of substring by '=' sepearator
        const contentDispositionHeaderResult = contentDispositionHeader.split(';')[1].trim().split('=')[1];

        // the g mean global, so it will replace all the matched substring which in this case is /"/ with empty space
        const contentDispositionFileName = contentDispositionHeaderResult.replace(/"/g, '');

        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
        link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(d);
        link.download = contentDispositionFileName;
        link.click();
    }      
})
```

Below shows a reference that I used when I try to solve this issue:-

- [Type 'Buffer' is not assignable to type 'BlobPart'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53714922/type-buffer-is-not-assignable-to-type-blobpart)
- [Angular HttpClient: Property 'headers' does not exist on type 'Blob'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49504953/angular-httpclient-property-headers-does-not-exist-on-type-blob)
- [Unable to view 'Content-Disposition' headers in Angular4 GET response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45892875/unable-to-view-content-disposition-headers-in-angular4-get-response/45920390#comment126410739_45920390)

Hope this can help anyone.